# Getting 'Cannot read property "length" from undefined' exception while rendering chart at JasperReports Server

Tags: charts, highcharts, jasper-reports, jasperserver

While generating report with high chart stacked lines getting

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined (com/jaspersoft/jasperreports/highcharts/charts/render/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js#4)
```

Full trace

```
    2016-08-04 01:32:43,508 ERROR AsyncThumbnailCreatorImpl,pool-29-thread-2:59 - net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined (com/jaspersoft/jasperreports/highcharts/charts/render/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js#4)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined (com/jaspersoft/jasperreports/highcharts/charts/render/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js#4)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.charts.ChartGraphics2DHandler.exportElement(ChartGraphics2DHandler.java:52)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.draw.FrameDrawer.draw(FrameDrawer.java:246)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.draw.FrameDrawer.draw(FrameDrawer.java:198)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRGraphics2DExporter.exportPage(JRGraphics2DExporter.java:342)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRGraphics2DExporter.exportReportToGraphics2D(JRGraphics2DExporter.java:311)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRGraphics2DExporter.exportReport(JRGraphics2DExporter.java:236)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.print.JRPrinterAWT.printPageToImage(JRPrinterAWT.java:290)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrintManager.printToImage(JasperPrintManager.java:290)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.common.service.impl.ThumbnailGenerationServiceImpl.obtainImage(ThumbnailGenerationServiceImpl.java:71)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.common.service.impl.ThumbnailGenerationServiceImpl.createThumbnail(ThumbnailGenerationServiceImpl.java:50)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.common.service.impl.ThumbnailGenerationServiceImpl.createThumbnail(ThumbnailGenerationServiceImpl.java:24)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.common.service.impl.AsyncThumbnailCreatorImpl$ThumbnailRunnable.run(AsyncThumbnailCreatorImpl.java:55)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined (com/jaspersoft/jasperreports/highcharts/charts/render/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js#4)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3785)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3763)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3791)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3810)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.undefReadError(ScriptRuntime.java:3823)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1508)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1398)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:854)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:164)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:76)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_svg_renderer_highcharts_js_2._c_anonymous_7(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.svg-renderer-highcharts.js:46)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_svg_renderer_highcharts_js_2.call(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.svg-renderer-highcharts.js)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2521)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:300)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:129)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:76)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_r_js_1._c_anonymous_99(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.r.js:1889)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_r_js_1.call(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.r.js)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:86)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_r_js_1._c_anonymous_55(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.r.js:1105)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_r_js_1.call(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.r.js)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callProp0(OptRuntime.java:119)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_r_js_1._c_anonymous_67(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.r.js:1382)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_r_js_1.call(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.r.js)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callProp0(OptRuntime.java:119)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_r_js_1._c_anonymous_49(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.r.js:1013)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_r_js_1.call(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.r.js)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:86)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_r_js_1._c_anonymous_89(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.r.js:1655)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_r_js_1.call(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.r.js)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:57)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_r_js_1._c_anonymous_104(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.r.js:1996)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_r_js_1.call(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.r.js)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:66)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_r_js_1._c_localRequire_88(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.r.js:1644)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_r_js_1.call(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.r.js)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:86)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_r_js_1._c_anonymous_102(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.r.js:1976)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_r_js_1.call(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.r.js)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:97)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_svg_renderer_highcharts_js_2._c_anonymous_6(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.svg-renderer-highcharts.js:45)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_svg_renderer_highcharts_js_2.call(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.svg-renderer-highcharts.js)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2521)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:300)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:129)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1701)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:854)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:164)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:76)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_svg_renderer_highcharts_js_2._c_anonymous_5(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.svg-renderer-highcharts.js:41)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_svg_renderer_highcharts_js_2.call(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.svg-renderer-highcharts.js)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2521)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:300)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:129)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:76)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_r_js_1._c_anonymous_99(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.r.js:1889)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_r_js_1.call(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.r.js)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:86)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_r_js_1._c_anonymous_55(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.r.js:1105)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_r_js_1.call(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.r.js)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callProp0(OptRuntime.java:119)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_r_js_1._c_anonymous_67(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.r.js:1382)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_r_js_1.call(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.r.js)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callProp0(OptRuntime.java:119)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_r_js_1._c_anonymous_49(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.r.js:1013)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_r_js_1.call(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.r.js)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:86)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_r_js_1._c_anonymous_89(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.r.js:1655)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_r_js_1.call(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.r.js)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:57)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_r_js_1._c_anonymous_104(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.r.js:1996)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_r_js_1.call(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.r.js)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:66)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_r_js_1._c_localRequire_88(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.r.js:1644)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_r_js_1.call(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.r.js)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:86)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_r_js_1._c_anonymous_102(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.r.js:1976)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_r_js_1.call(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.r.js)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:97)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_svg_renderer_highcharts_js_2._c_renderSVGFromJson_4(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.svg-renderer-highcharts.js:31)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.com_jaspersoft_jasperreports_highcharts_render_svg_renderer_highcharts_js_2.call(com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.render.svg-renderer-highcharts.js)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1701)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:854)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:164)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:426)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3178)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:175)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.evaluateString(Context.java:1111)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.charts.render.RhinoChartSvgProducer.getChartSvg(RhinoChartSvgProducer.java:104)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.charts.render.DefaultChartSvgProducer.getChartSvg(DefaultChartSvgProducer.java:39)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.charts.render.ChartSvgImageProducer.createRenderable(ChartSvgImageProducer.java:81)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.charts.render.ChartSvgImageProducer.getChartImage(ChartSvgImageProducer.java:45)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.charts.ChartGraphics2DHandler.exportElement(ChartGraphics2DHandler.java:47)
        ... 16 more
```

Jrxml file is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="AbandonedWorkflowPercentage" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="fc97a963-c0b6-4c19-a348-7e2773e092a3">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="DM"/>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[SELECT ...]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="INTERVALS" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <field name="PERCENTAGE_TO_GOAL" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="TOTAL" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="SERIES" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <summary>
        <band height="550" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="50" width="700" height="500" uuid="edf50a68-78c7-45b6-8246-57d927666a3d">
                </reportElement>
                <hc:chart xmlns:hc="http://jaspersoft.com/highcharts" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jaspersoft.com/highcharts http://jaspersoft.com/schema/highcharts.xsd" type="StackedLine">
                    <hc:chartSetting name="default">
                        <hc:chartProperty name="chart.zoomType">
                            <hc:propertyExpression><![CDATA["xy"]]></hc:propertyExpression>
                        </hc:chartProperty>
                        <hc:chartProperty name="credits.enabled">
                            <hc:propertyExpression><![CDATA[false]]></hc:propertyExpression>
                        </hc:chartProperty>
                        <hc:chartProperty name="credits.href">
                            <hc:propertyExpression><![CDATA[""]]></hc:propertyExpression>
                        </hc:chartProperty>
                        <hc:chartProperty name="credits.text">
                            <hc:propertyExpression><![CDATA[""]]></hc:propertyExpression>
                        </hc:chartProperty>
                        <hc:chartProperty name="title.text">
                            <hc:propertyExpression><![CDATA[""]]></hc:propertyExpression>
                        </hc:chartProperty>
                        <hc:chartProperty name="xAxis.labels.rotation">
                            <hc:propertyExpression><![CDATA[new Integer(-45)]]></hc:propertyExpression>
                        </hc:chartProperty>
                        <hc:chartProperty name="yAxis.title.text">
                            <hc:propertyExpression><![CDATA["Percent To Goal"]]></hc:propertyExpression>
                        </hc:chartProperty>
                    </hc:chartSetting>
                    <multiAxisData>
                        <multiAxisDataset/>
                        <dataAxis axis="Rows">
                            <axisLevel name="Interval">
                                <labelExpression><![CDATA["Level Label expression"]]></labelExpression>
                                <axisLevelBucket class="java.lang.String">
                                    <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{INTERVALS}]]></bucketExpression>
                                </axisLevelBucket>
                            </axisLevel>
                        </dataAxis>
                        <dataAxis axis="Columns">
                            <axisLevel name="series">
                                <labelExpression><![CDATA[]]></labelExpression>
                                <axisLevelBucket order="None" class="java.lang.String">
                                    <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{SERIES}]]></bucketExpression>
                                </axisLevelBucket>
                            </axisLevel>
                        </dataAxis>
                        <multiAxisMeasure name="PercentToGoal" class="java.math.BigDecimal" calculation="Nothing">
                            <labelExpression><![CDATA[""]]></labelExpression>
                            <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{PERCENTAGE_TO_GOAL}]]></valueExpression>
                        </multiAxisMeasure>
                    </multiAxisData>
                    <hc:series name="PercentToGoal"/>
                </hc:chart>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

There are not compile error and SQL is returning empty data. So report prints "Empty report" but after that there are above exceptions in the logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is solved.

When the data set is empty high chart still try to render the chart and it will fail. To prevent it added print when condition for chart element in report jrxml.

```
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT} > 0]]></printWhenExpression>
```